# Symfony : Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, repository, entity

I'm new on Symfony 6 and i've got some questions about this framework.
Recently i got this error but i don't understand why. I created all databases from the command line.

My error is : Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names: "App\Entity\tag" vs "App\Entity\Tag".

In my database all tables are written with lowercase syntaxe.
everything worked between I insert relation with all table.

i tried to insert this code in my entity to use the correct syntaxe but it doesn't work.

Entity\Tag.php

```
#[ORM\Table(name: 'tag')]
```

Some people speak about this parameter inside my database (MYSQL) but i don't know if this got an impact :

```
lower_case_table_names = (0 1 2)
```

Do you have an idea ?

This is my entity tag

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\TagRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: TagRepository::class)]


class Tag
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]

    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $nomtag = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'idcatetag')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?catetag $idcatetag = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Mission::class, mappedBy: 'idtagmissionassign')]
    private Collection $missions;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Service::class, mappedBy: 'idtagserviceassign')]
    private Collection $services;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->missions = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->services = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNomtag(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nomtag;
    }

    public function setNomtag(string $nomtag): self
    {
        $this->nomtag = $nomtag;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdcatetag(): ?catetag
    {
        return $this->idcatetag;
    }

    public function setIdcatetag(?catetag $idcatetag): self
    {
        $this->idcatetag = $idcatetag;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Mission>
     */
    public function getMissions(): Collection
    {
        return $this->missions;
    }

    public function addMission(Mission $mission): self
    {
        if (!$this->missions->contains($mission)) {
            $this->missions->add($mission);
            $mission->addIdtagmissionassign($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMission(Mission $mission): self
    {
        if ($this->missions->removeElement($mission)) {
            $mission->removeIdtagmissionassign($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Service>
     */
    public function getServices(): Collection
    {
        return $this->services;
    }

    public function addService(Service $service): self
    {
        if (!$this->services->contains($service)) {
            $this->services->add($service);
            $service->addIdtagserviceassign($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeService(Service $service): self
    {
        if ($this->services->removeElement($service)) {
            $service->removeIdtagserviceassign($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This is my repo file :

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Tag;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @extends ServiceEntityRepository<Tag>
 *
 * @method Tag|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Tag|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Tag[]    findAll()
 * @method Tag[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class TagRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Tag::class);
    }

    public function save(Tag $entity, bool $flush = false): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);

        if ($flush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }

    public function remove(Tag $entity, bool $flush = false): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->remove($entity);

        if ($flush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }

//    /**
//     * @return Tag[] Returns an array of Tag objects
//     */
//    public function findByExampleField($value): array
//    {
//        return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
//            ->andWhere('t.exampleField = :val')
//            ->setParameter('val', $value)
//            ->orderBy('t.id', 'ASC')
//            ->setMaxResults(10)
//            ->getQuery()
//            ->getResult()
//        ;
//    }

//    public function findOneBySomeField($value): ?Tag
//    {
//        return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
//            ->andWhere('t.exampleField = :val')
//            ->setParameter('val', $value)
//            ->getQuery()
//            ->getOneOrNullResult()
//        ;
//    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that it is trying to load Entity/tag somewhere ? Did you try to `php bin/console cache:clear` ? And to check if some controller try to use Entity/tag instead of Entity/Tag

Comment: how did you created the entity? you could try creating by make:entity command.

Comment: php bin/console cache:clear i have already done this... with no success ...

Comment: php bin/console make:entity  tag for example.

Comment: It's not related to tables or database. You have call the Tag entity somewhere , maybe in a controller with lowercase "tag"  not Tag"

Comment: Do a search for `use App\Entity\tag` and `App\Entity\tag` across your entire project, you will be including a namespace with a lowercase `tag` somewhere. Also check your class filenames have the correct case so the tag entity should be name `Tag.php`. As mentioned also clear cache after you have made your changes `bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: Mysql does have this rather interesting `feature` in which the [case sensitivity of table names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) depends on the server's operating system.  That is what the `lower_case_table_names` setting is all about but it is seldom a factor. But as other folks have pointed out you probably just have a typo someplace.  In particular, make sure that and other entities that reference the Tag entity have the correct spelling.  It's not always obvious inside of an attribute.

Comment: Hello back, Thank for helping me. I don't found the problem yet. I've searched for App\Entity\tag but nothing show up in the entire project. Where does it come from ...

Comment: The fact that you have classes with names like `catetag` really makes me think that you are not being consistent with your class names.  Maybe create a new Symfony app and then recreate your entities until you encounter the error.

Answer (score 0):

check file name , it should be Tag.php with T uppercase, symfony create table automatically in lowercase. If everything is ok try to delete you're file and rewrite it properly with make:entity or php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force after entity's modification

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Okay the subject has been resolved. In my mission class there where #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: tag::class, inversedBy: 'missions')]. whitch tag in lowercase. After correct that with 'Tag'. All works. Thank's for helping me :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue right now. The problem is hard to find due to it not being in any of those files and chat GPT always tells you to check your entity and your repo. The thing is that entity is related to others and in those other entities there are instances of 'tag' instead of 'Tag'. Allow me to show you with my code how I fixed this:
[This is my error (same as yours)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jT5u.png)

I will not bother with the Grupo entity (your Tag) as it is correct, however let me show you my RelGrupoEvento entity:

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Entity;

 use App\Repository\RelGrupoEventoRepository;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 #[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: RelGrupoEventoRepository::class)]
 class RelGrupoEvento
 {
 #[ORM\Id]
 #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
 #[ORM\Column]
 private ?int $id = null;
 
 #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'relGrupoEventos')]
 #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
 private ?grupo $grupo = null;
 
 #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'relGrupoEventos')]
 #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
 private ?Evento $evento = null;

 #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
 private ?int $puntuacionEventoGrupo = null;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

As you can see the grupo attribute is where the case mismatch is ( 'private ?grupo $grupo = null;' should be 'private ?Grupo $grupo = null;'). So check all related entities for instances of tag. The issue is most likely and attribute but it could be in a method call too.